# Running a Remote SonarQube server with access from various machines

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket

I am trying to set up a dedicated remote server to run SonarQube so it can run code analysis and code coverage. The issue that I am facing is that I want to be able to access this server from various other machines on the same network. Is it possible to host sonarqube on a separate machine from where the codebase is? Ideally i would like to sync sonarqube to pull code from my master branch which is currently in bitbucket.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube doesn't require to be hosted on the same server where a codebase is. You should execute a scanner on your build server and the scanner will push data to SonarQube.

here is a documentation about SonarQube Architecture and Integration: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+and+Integration

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SonarQube to be hosted on same server. You can use SonarScanner as client to connect and run analysis on remote SonarQube server.

Do a git clone of your repository on any of the servers and provide this as an input/argument to SonarScanner executor.

Read more about SonarScanner here :
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner